# Moving an Android app file from one drive to another gives errors

Tags: android, directory, move

I made a working android app using eclipse, but got a new hard drive. The app folder and all files are saved on the old drive. I copied the eclipse folder to the new drive, but it gives several errors, including "missing styles" and the "findviewbyId" functions not working. Is there any way to successfully move the folder to Eclipse in the new drive?

Answer (score 0):

Create an Android Project from Existing code.

Go to File -> New -> Other -> Android Project from Existing Code. Select the directory of the project and copy it to your workspace. That usually works for me without errors.

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when you added a library and did not give it a trip to your new hard drive . Check again if you are missing any libraries .You might be using styles from the library hence if the library isn't there , you get errors.